# Draw arc in overlay option for tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm drawing arc in overlay mode in tikz, but the result is not what I want.
The arc I want seems like:
[image]

However, when I use overlay and remember picture options, the result is
[image]

Code I use:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=1cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows, patterns,patterns.meta,hobby} 
\begin{document}
\definecolor{darkteal}{RGB}{16,162,163}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \coordinate (A) at (current page.north west);
    \coordinate (A1) at ([yshift=-0.4\paperheight]current page.north west);
    \coordinate (B1) at ([yshift=-0.4\paperheight]current page.north east);
    \coordinate (A2) at ([yshift=-0.6\paperheight]current page.north west);
    \coordinate (B2) at ([yshift=-0.6\paperheight]current page.north east);
    \draw[darkteal] (B2) arc ({90+asin(0.9)}:180:20);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thank everyone !!

Comment: I don't quite understand why you would expect the output to be like in the first picture. You draw an arc from `(B2)` which you define to be somewhere below the upper right corner of the page. So, it seems only natural that the arc sits at the right side of the page, doesn't it? The output of the second picture seems totally right to me. Maybe tell a bit more about what you want to do eventually.

Comment: Oh, now that I read Skillmon's answer, I understand where you got confused. Note that there is another preferred syntax for `arc`: `arc ({90+asin(0.9)}:180:20)` would be written like `arc[start angle={90+asin(0.9)}, end angle={180}, radius={20}]`.

Comment: Thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

Your misunderstanding seems to be that the coordinate at which you use `arc` isn't the centre point of the arc, but the starting point of it (and the centre lies 20cm to the right of it).

If you move your starting point (for instance by using the same angle and radius in `++(<ang>:<radius>)`) you get what you intend (I removed the unrelated packages from your preamble):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=1cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows, patterns,patterns.meta,hobby} 
\begin{document}
\definecolor{darkteal}{RGB}{16,162,163}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \coordinate (A) at (current page.north west);
    \coordinate (A1) at ([yshift=-0.4\paperheight]current page.north west);
    \coordinate (B1) at ([yshift=-0.4\paperheight]current page.north east);
    \coordinate (A2) at ([yshift=-0.6\paperheight]current page.north west);
    \coordinate (B2) at ([yshift=-0.6\paperheight]current page.north east);
    \draw[darkteal] (B2) ++({90+asin(0.9)}:20cm) arc ({90+asin(0.9)}:180:20cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!